# SonarQube Github Action for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, sonarqube, github-actions

I am trying to setup SonarQube for a project hosted on Github. The settings offered in the SonarQube UI are good, despite the fact that the project uses the Objective-C programming language. The Github Action I am using is

```
jobs:
  sonarcloud:
    name: SonarCloud
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

and it fails with

```
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 

The only way to get an accurate analysis of C/C++/Objective-C files is by using the
SonarSource build-wrapper and setting the property "sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output" 
or by using Clang Compilation Database and setting the property 
"sonar.cfamily.compile-commands". None of these two options were specified.
```

Is there some Github Action that will run the SonarSource build-wrapper, or what would be the best next step?

Comment: See these threads for examples and relevant resources: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75531993/github-sonarcloud-action-does-not-scan-any-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192071/sonarcloud-with-googletest-and-cmake-on-github-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I extended my workflow as follows. There are a few caveats:

- there is a nice Github Action 'SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-c-cpp@v1'. Is this sufficient to analyze Objective-C projects?
- Git checkout will remove unnecessary directories. Hence you must install SonarQube AFTER having checkout out your source
- The build wrapper just monitors the actual build, so you still have to run the Sonar Scanner afterwards

Here is the resulting code:

```
jobs:
  SonarQube:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR: build_wrapper_output_directory

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
          submodules: recursive
      
      - name: Install sonar-scanner and build-wrapper
        uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-c-cpp@v1

      - name: Run build-wrapper
        run: |
          build-wrapper-linux-x86-64 --out-dir ${{ env.BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR }} make -f Makefile pkg-posix-nightly HOST_ARCH=$(uname -m)

      - name: Run sonar-scanner
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONARCLOUD_TOKEN }} # Put the name of your token here
        run: |
          sonar-scanner --define sonar.cfamily.build-wrapper-output="${{ env.BUILD_WRAPPER_OUT_DIR }}"
```